# WPF UserControl Navigating with Enum Tags

Tags: c#, wpf, enums

I use a Enum to fill my ListView with items.

After filling I want to get the specific usercontrol after an onclick,
with the Enum tag or something else.

I use the `Description` to specify the Item Name. But
I also want to bind for each Enum his UserControl.

I would like to do it Like (Pseudo Code):

```
onClick(object sender, Args....){
ItemXY foo = sender as ItemXY
this.UserControl = foo.getUserControl();
...
}
```

my enum:

```
 public enum UserControlsEnum
{
    [Description("Cash")]
    Cash     =   0,
    [Description("History")]
    Velocity =   1,
    [Description("Statistik")]
    Statistik =   2,
    [Description("Information")]
    Info        =   3,
    [Description("Administration")]
    Admin       =   4,
    [Description("About")]
    About       =   5
}
```

**My Question is:**

Is there any tag like Description to set the Name of the specific View as a String or even better the Specific View directly ?

like:

```
    [Description("Cash")]
 -->[Tag("ItemView.xaml")]
    Cash     =   0,
```

Comment: You can add custom attributes, sure, but they're not magic.  You also have to build something that _looks for_ that attribute and _does something_ with it.  There's not a built-in attribute to map enum values to views.

Comment: How would the sender of a Click event ever be an enum?

Comment: Does `ListView` displays enum members (I mean, each row is a visual representation of enum member)? What do you want to do ultimately?

Comment: You can write a set of `DataTemplate`s which contain the desired views, then write a `DataTemplateSelector` which returns the appropriate template based on the enum value you give it. You could write a custom attribute class that has a resource key, and apply that attribute to your enum values. It's a fair amount of code but nothing technically challenging. You could also try writing a single ItemTemplate for the ListView which contains a ContentControl and has a set of triggers which change the ContentControl's ContentTemplate based on the enum value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work :

```
public sealed class ViewTagAttribute : Attribute
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="viewType"></param>
    public ViewTagAttribute(System.Type viewType)
    {
        this.type = viewType;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Create an instance of the associated view
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static View CreateViewInstanceForEnumValue<T>(T enumValue)
    {
        var attributes = typeof(T).GetField(enumValue.ToString()).GetCustomAttributes(true);
        var viewAttr = (from a in attributes where a is ViewTagAttribute select (ViewTagAttribute)a).FirstOrDefault();

        if (viewAttr != null)
            return System.Activator.CreateInstance(viewAttr.type) as View;

        return null;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Associated view type
    /// </summary>
    private readonly System.Type type;
}
```

You can then set the control for each enum member using the ViewTag attribute, e.g. :

```
public enum UserControlsEnum
{
    [Description("Cash")]
    [ViewTag(typeof(View1))]
    Cash = 0,

    [Description("History")]
    [ViewTag(typeof(View2))]
    Velocity = 1,

    [Description("Statistik")]
    [ViewTag(typeof(View3))]
    Statistik = 2,

    [Description("Information")]
    [ViewTag(typeof(View1))]
    Info = 3,

    [Description("Administration")]
    [ViewTag(typeof(View1))]
    Admin = 4,

    [Description("About")]
    [ViewTag(typeof(View1))]
    About = 5
}
```

Then you can create the view using something like :

```
this.UserControl = (UserControl)ViewTagAttribute.CreateViewInstanceForEnumValue(foo);
```

Comment: I get an error on System.Activator.CreateInstance(viewAttr.type) as View; that View is not nullable

Comment: Try replacing View with UserControl